# Linked list basic memory(in C)

Tags: c, list, memory, memory-address

I was trying to understand better how the memory in the linked list is allocated so I made a simple program in order to see where the addresses are stored.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

int main()
{

    struct node first;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;
    struct node *aux; //pointer to go through list

    first.data = 1;
    second.data = 2;
    third.data = 3;

    first.next = &second;
    second.next = &third;
    third.next = NULL;
    aux = &first;

    while (aux) 
    {
        printf("%p\n", aux); //printing each address 
        aux = aux->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And we get the output:

```
0x7fff14fabac0
0x7fff14fabad0
0x7fff14fabae0
```

So there is 1 byte difference between nodes.

So basically first = second - 1. How come there are spaces in memory left for integers since sizeof(int) equals 4 bytes, and we advance only by 1 byte?

Comment: It's `16` bytes.

Comment: That clears it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the last digit, the difference is 16 bytes. The 16 bytes are most likely a result of 8 byte alignment of your system.